# intelliJ debug not finding file in target folder

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

Hello I have an appengine module that won't work properly since I change my old appengine plugin to the new google cloud tools.

I have a module that is a child of my project.
I have a maven directive to copy some files from another child modules to the target folder of my module target/artifcat-name/WEB-INF.
The copy works.
But when I debug the appengine module in Intellij, I have a FileNotFoundException while trying to read the copied file from the target dir.

It worked fine before the update.

It also works fine when I run the devserver from the shell (mvn appengine:devserver.

I don't what I should change in Intellij to have it working again.

Ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Alex. I'm guessing you are using the "Google App Engine Standard Local Server" run configuration to run the devserver from IJ? I suspect that maybe the issue is that this run configuration is ignoring your maven directive. Could you try editing the exploded-war artifact and adding the files manually to your WEB-INF? (Project Settings -> Artifacts).

Comment: Hello @eshaul,

I have tried many things.

I have reinstalled intellij, reimported the project.
I have added the Resources in the facet like so :
<project-dir>/<module-dir>/target/<folder where files are copied by mvn resource plugin> | WEB-INF (first part is the "Web Resource Directory," second part is the "Path Relative to Deployment Root").
I Have also added the files in the artifact conf.
But I'm still getting the FileNotFoundException. The File I'm trying to read is present in <project-dir>/<module-dir>target/<module-name>/WEB-INF/.

Comment: Actually, I also have files in the source web-inf folder of the module. These files get copied to the target folder. And I am also not able to read those files.
It seems that in run, debug in Intellij, I am not able to access files in the WEB-INF folder.